# Merge two linked lists

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic, linked-list

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to merge two linked lists. Basically I am trying to combine the lists like below,
S = [1, 9, 5, 3] and Q = [0, 4, 3, 6, 6, 2] and result should be [1, 0, 4, 9, 5, 3, 6, 3,6, 2]

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class IntList {
    public int first;

    public IntList rest;

    public IntList(int first0, IntList rest0) {
        first = first0;
        rest = rest0;
    }
    public IntList() {
        this(0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return first;
    }

    public static IntList of(Integer... args) {
        IntList result, p;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            result = new IntList(args[0], null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        int k;
        for (k = 1, p = result; k < args.length; k += 1, p = p.rest) {
            p.rest = new IntList(args[k], null);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x) {
        if (!(x instanceof IntList)) {
            return false;
        }
        IntList L = (IntList) x;
        IntList p;

        for (p = this; p != null && L != null; p = p.rest, L = L.rest) {
            if (p.first != L.first) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (p != null || L != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

 
    private int detectCycles(IntList A) {
        IntList tortoise = A;
        IntList hare = A;

        if (A == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int cnt = 0;

        while (true) {
            cnt++;
            if (hare.rest != null) {
                hare = hare.rest.rest;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

            tortoise = tortoise.rest;

            if (tortoise == null || hare == null) {
                return 0;
            }

            if (hare == tortoise) {
                return cnt;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Formatter out = new Formatter();
        String sep;
        sep = "(";
        int cycleLocation = detectCycles(this);
        int cnt = 0;

        for (IntList p = this; p != null; p = p.rest) {
            out.format("%s%d", sep, p.first);
            sep = ", ";

            cnt++;
            if ((cnt > cycleLocation) && (cycleLocation > 0)) {
                out.format("... (cycle exists) ...");
                break;
            }
        }
        out.format(")");
        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone can suggest an algorithm to achieve this.

```
public static IntList merge(IntList S, IntList Q) {
    //body
}
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
public static IntList merge(IntList S, IntList Q) {
    if (S == null) {
        return Q;
    } else if (Q == null) {
        return S;
    } else {
        return new IntList(S.first, merge(Q.rest, S));
    }
}
```

[image: Resulting Linked List]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a do-your-homework-for-you type of service. Please make a good faith attempt to implement this merge function before asking questions here. Check out these articles for more guidance on posting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: public static IntList merge(IntList S, IntList Q) {
        if (S == null) {
            return Q;
        } else if (Q == null) {
            return S;
        } else {
            return new IntList(S.first, snakeweave(Q.rest, S));
        }

    }

This is what I have done so far. But I am not going no where with it

Comment: That looks like a good start. Please paste it into the question since it is unreadable and because it’s always best to have everything in one place. Are `merge()` and `snakeWeave()` two different methods and if so, what is the difference between their intended behaviour?

Comment: If you’re fine with a recursive solution, you should generally take the concatenation of the first element from `s`, the first element from `q` and the result from merging `q.rest` and `s.rest` in this order (note the swapping of `s` and `q` in the recursive call). Add necessary null checks.

Comment: Author is posting their homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your attempt was going in the right direction, but in the recursive step, don't only take the first value from the first list, also take the first value from the second list, and call a recursive merge on both "rests" of the lists.

So change this line:

```
return new IntList(S.first, merge(Q.rest, S));
```

to:

```
return new IntList(S.first, new IntList(Q.first, merge(Q.rest, S.rest)));
```